# Is $H_0^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap H^2(\mathbb{R})$ compactly embedded into $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to prove that $H_0^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap H^2(\mathbb{R})$ compactly embedded into $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I have been using the template of the proof from the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem but I cannot find precisely what I want... Does anyone have a nice way to prove this result?

Best wishes,

Catherine

Comment: Since $H^1_0(\mathbb{R})=H^1(\mathbb{R})$, what you want to prove is not true.

Comment: I thought that $H_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ are the functions with first derivatives that vanish at infinity?

Comment: What is your definition of $H_0^1$? If it's the closure (in $H^1$) of smooth compactly supported functions, then the equality I mentioned holds.